# Comparing .wav samples from command line

Tags: command-line, utilities, wav

As a part of our project we should classify sound samples (stored as .wav files). All sample is the same, just pure speech (like a Skype test call).

The process is the following:

- a reference wav, this is the "high quality" sample
- comparing approx. 1000 wav files
- calculating divergence from the reference wav one by one

Is there any Linux tool for that?

Comment: Do you need only to compare the files, or you want to listen to the differences?

Comment: Yes, it's about "hearing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I believe you are trying to measure (by stating *divergence*) is the **PESQ**, Perceptual Evaluation of Speech Quality, of each file. This is a standarized form ITU-T recommendation P.862 (02/01) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ.

You have different projects implementing what you are searching for. For example
https://github.com/imankulov/speex-quality-evaluation

Comment: Thank you and there is a reference implementation too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329403/how-to-start-a-voice-quality-pesq-test